# Loading JSON with jQuery, then displaying it to the viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I'm trying to load a JSON file using the [DataPoint API of the Met Office](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint) by calling the URL:

http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=[MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE]

A sample of the returned JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "Locations": {
        "Location": [
            {
                "elevation": "228.0",
                "id": "3063",
                "latitude": "57.206",
                "longitude": "-3.827",
                "name": "Aviemore",
                "nationalPark": "Cairngorms National Park",
                "region": "he",
                "unitaryAuthArea": "Highland"
            },
            {
                "elevation": "1245.0",
                "id": "3065",
                "latitude": "57.116",
                "longitude": "-3.642",
                "name": "Cairn Gorm Summit",
                "nationalPark": "Cairngorms National Park",
                "region": "he",
                "unitaryAuthArea": "Moray"
            },
            {
                "elevation": "146.0",
                "id": "3238",
                "latitude": "55.02",
                "longitude": "-1.88",
                "name": "Albemarle",
                "region": "ne",
                "unitaryAuthArea": "Northumberland"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need to do is display the list of locations. And for that I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#driver").click(function(event){
        $.getJSON('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=' + MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE, function(jd) {
            $('#stage').html('<p> locations: ' + jd.locations + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p>location: ' + jd.location + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p> name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
        });
    });

});
```

But it fails to load every time, I've followed many tutorials, all of which seem to have been no help. Why is the list of locations failing?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have access restriction to the url. ;)

Comment: The URL loads fine when I use my API key.

Comment: In the console, do you get any errors? `jd.locations` is nothing (it would be `jd.Locations`), `jd.location` is nothing (it would be an array if you do `jd.Locations.Location`), and `jd.name` is nothing too (it would be a string if you did `jd.Locations.Location[x].name`)

Comment: I think it's a bad edit that you made there. Your question doesn't make sense without the code or the context of the API.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON()` call is correct (I found a key online from another SO person that was not as careful as you were, and I used his/her key temporarily to test).

After you get the results, you are reading the JSON incorrectly:

```
$('#stage').html('<p> locations: ' + jd.locations + '</p>');
$('#stage').append('<p>location: ' + jd.location+ '</p>');
$('#stage').append('<p> name: ' + jd.name+ '</p>');
```

That's wrong. You need to **take into account upper and lower case, the different data types** (it's not the same an object, an array, and a string), **and how they are structured**:

- Instead of `jd.locations`, use `jd.Locations`
- Instead of `jd.location`, use `jd.Locations.Location`
- Instead of `jd.name`, use `jd.Locations.Location[`***`x`***`].name` (where ***`x`*** is the index of the location)

Once you take that into account, just loop through the location records:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#driver").click(function(event) {
       $.getJSON('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=(KEYGOESHERE)', function(jd) {
            $('#stage').html('<p> There are  ' + jd.Locations.Location.length + ' locations</p>');
            for (var x = 0; x < jd.Locations.Location.length; x++) {
                $('#stage').append('<p>location: ' + jd.Locations.Location[x].name + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code above will result in something like this:

> There are 5968 locations
>
> location: Cairnwell
>
> location: Inverbervie
>
> location: Rosehearty Samos
>
> location: Strathallan
>
> ....

Answer (score 0):

As Nielarshi suggested, you need the same origin domain,  or [jsonp callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) allowed on the api resource. Or at least, [allowed cross domain requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx) enabled on the backend web server.

From [JQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

You also have to be sure about the response header "Content-Type". If is "application/json" you can use the data as you did, if not, you need to parse the string with `var object = JSON.parse(jd)`